# How to get a uuid with python requests

Tags: python, http, post, authentication, python-requests

I am attempting to log into a web page using the python requests module but the Post data on the website that I want to log into includes a uuid tag.

```
pass: ********
user: ********
uuid: ********
```

I have thoroughly searched for any mention of this anywhere in most requests documentation. Is this simply out of the capabilities of the program or is it something that I am overlooking.

This is the code I am using.

```
import requests

url = 'www.website.com'

with requests.Session() as c:
     c.get(url)
     values = {'pass': 'passsword', 'user': 'username'}
     response = c.post(url, data=values)
     print response
```

Comment: Why don't you pass it along with the other data?

Comment: I cant seem to obtain the uuid from the website I just don't know if requests even does that

Comment: But this has nothing to do with requests. Surely you obtain the uuid from the same place you get the username and password.

Comment: This script is to log into a web page the user provides the username and password. The requests module should maintain cookie data, but this additional uuid field is confusing me. And the script still cannot access the protected url.

Comment: What is the website?

Comment: http://myneu.neu.edu/cp/home/displaylogin

Comment: There's no reference to a UUID on that page. Why do you think you need one?

Comment: When you send a POST to login it includes one in the form data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse it from the source:

```
In [29]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [30]: import re

In [31]: patt = re.compile("document.cplogin.uuid.value=\"(.*?)\"")

In [32]: with requests.Session() as s:
   ....:         page = s.get('http://myneu.neu.edu/cp/home/displaylogin').content
   ....:         soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
   ....:         script = soup.find("script", language="javascript1.1")
   ....:         uuid = patt.search(script.text).group(1)
   ....:     

In [33]: uuid
Out[33]: u'ff3e7ddd-0823-4f44-a003-0e68a9321e08'
```

If you look at the source of the login page, inside the script with the attribute *language="javascript1.1"*, you can see the uuid:

```
function login()
{
    setQueryAsCookie();
    document.cplogin.user.value=document.userid.user.value;
    document.cplogin.uuid.value="21fbc26a-3a3d-4802-ba4a-39a40aad881c";
    document.cplogin.submit();
}
```

So just pass that along with the rest of the form data when you post.

The post url also seems to be *https://myneu.neu.edu/cp/home/login*, so:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

patt = re.compile("document.cplogin.uuid.value=\"(.*?)\"")
data = {"user":"uname", "pass":"passw"}
post = "https://myneu.neu.edu/cp/home/login"

with requests.Session() as s:
    page = s.get('http://myneu.neu.edu/cp/home/displaylogin')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    script = soup.find("script", language="javascript1.1")
    uuid = patt.search(script.text).group(1)
    data["uuid"] = uuid
    resp = s.post(post, data=data)
```

Comment: That works but it seems like my issue is being cause by a different problem now. I still am rejected from the protected page. This is more difficult than I though.

Comment: What is returned from the post?

Comment: <Response [405]>
And if I attempt to access a restricted webpage then it redirects me to a login request page

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I cant believe I missed that the login form was posting to a different url. Now that you mention it I cant believe I missed it!